# My Asp GridView not displays its items

Tags: asp.net, gridview

i have asp GridView

```
   <asp:GridView ID="uploadedSoundDataGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"     EmptyDataText = "No files uploaded"/>
```

and some code on pageload to display files in a directory

```
   if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/"));
            List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
            foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
            {
                files.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath));
            }
            uploadedSoundDataGridView.DataSource = files;
            uploadedSoundDataGridView.DataBind();
        }
```

I can take all file names and i can bind them to GridView(i checked it with quickwatch). But in my page i cant see GridView. Does anyone tell me why? Thank you

Comment: In gridview markup set `AutoGenerateColumns = "true"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your gridview change this property :

```
  AutoGenerateColumns = "false"
```

to :

```
  AutoGenerateColumns = "true"
```